# Conditional distribution function question

Tags: self-study

is it correct to use this formula as the basis?:
[image]

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: It seems like there's context missing from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability distribition of $X$ given $N=n$ is a binomial distribution with $B(n,p)$.
The task then is to calculate the unconditional distribution which is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty B(n,p) \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} exp{-\lambda},
$$
which I think can be done if you look at the binomial coefficient.

If you look at the mgf then
$$
E[exp(t X)|N=n] = (1-p+p e^t)^n,
$$
and the unconditional is
$$
E[(1-p+p e^t)^N] = E[s^N]
$$
where $s = (1-p+p e^t)$. The above expression is the probability generating function given by 
$$
\exp(\lambda (s-1) )
$$
and if you plugin then it is
$$
\exp(\lambda ((1-p+p e^t)-1) ).
$$

Such distributions are called mixture-distributions. E.g. a Poisson distribution with $\lambda$ Gamma distributed turns out to be a negative binomial.

Comment: Thank you so much Richard for putting in the time to write this. I will mull over your answer as I work through the problem - it was a huge help so thank you!